# Java - Displaying the temperature statistics of the week using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a problem set for an assignment at school, and I'm really close to finishing however I'm getting a few compilation errors.

The problem set includes displaying the weeks avg. temp, highest temp., lowest temp., and the days of the week that are hottest and coldest.

Currently what I'm trying to do is display the days of the week that are hottest, and if I work that out I can easily find the coldest days of the week.

I'm getting a few compilation errors when I try to compile the code which includes

- incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
- error: cannot find symbol

It would be great if I could get some guidance on what to do, I'm currently at lost right now.

http://ideone.com/rOqV2Z

```
public class test1
{
// Main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Create a new scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Set array list
    int[] tempList = new int[7];

    // Prompt user for input and store input
    System.out.println("Enter the hightest temperature of each day for a week (starting on Sunday): ");
        for(int i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++)
            tempList[i] = input.nextInt();

    // Averages temperature - @@@@@@@ ASK WHY IT THERE ARE SO MANY DECIMALS ON THE SIDE WHEN AVERAGE ALL 1's
    double avgTemp = avgTemp(tempList);
        System.out.printf("The average temperature of the week is: %.2f degree %n", avgTemp);

    // Display hottest temperature
    int maxTemp = maxTemp(tempList);
        System.out.println("The highest temperature of the week is: " + maxTemp + " degree");

    // Display coldest temperature
    int minTemp = minTemp(tempList);
        System.out.println("The coldest temperature of the week is: " + minTemp + " degree");


    int[] maxTempList = searchTemp(tempList, maxTemp);

    for(int i = 0; i < maxTempList.length; i++){
        System.out.print("The hottest days of the week are: " +maxTempList[i]);

    System.out.print(weekDay(tempList,maxTemp));
    }
}

// Average the temperature
public static double avgTemp(int[] array)
{
    int tempTotal = array[0];

    // Total temperature values
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        tempTotal = array[i]+tempTotal;

    // Return temperature average.
    return ((double)tempTotal/array.length);
}

// Get hottest temperature
public static int maxTemp(int[] array)
{
    int max = array[0];

    // Check and replace max temp
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(max < array[i])
            max = array[i];

    }
    return max;
}

// Get coldest temperature
public static int minTemp(int[] array)
{
    int min = array[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        if(min > array[i])
            min = array[i];
    }
    return min;
}


// Return days
public static String weekDay(int i, int[] array)
{
    int[] displayWeekDay = searchTemp(array, i);

    for(i = 0; i < displayWeekDay.length; i++){

        String weekDay = "";
        switch(i)
        {
            case 0: return "Sunday";
            case 1: return "Monday";
            case 2: return "Tuesday";
            case 3: return "Wednesdays";
            case 4: return "Thursday";
            case 5: return "Friday";
            case 6: return "Saturday";
        }
    }
    return weekDay;
}


// Finds the index of the hottest/coldest days
public static int[] searchTemp(int[] temp, int key)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(temp[i] == key)
            count++;
    }

    int[] index = new int[count];
    for(int j = 0; j < index.length; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            if(temp[i] == key){
                if(j > 0 && index[j - 1] == i)
                    continue;
                else{
                    index[j] = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

}

Comment: I'd advise you to stop making that student mistake of focusing on user interactions and inputs to the exclusion of developing an API and thinking about how the calculations should work.  Get those right with hardwired or simple test inputs and then worry about how users will supply the data you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and checked the code using the website you linked.

1. Firstly, you should learn to use the debugger, as it will usually tell you what the error is and where to find it.

> ```
> Main.java:42: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
> System.out.print(weekDay(tempList,maxTemp));
>                              ^
> ```

Here it points to an error on the data type of `tempList`. It's saying that an int array cannot be converted to an int. If you look at the `weekDay()` function you'll see that the first argument is asking for an int, but you are passing an int array. It won't work.

```
public static String weekDay(int i, int[] array)
```

**EDIT**: If you want to pass a specific value into the function from the array just use

```
System.out.print(weekDay(tempList[IntegerPosition],maxTemp));
                                        ^
```

---

2. ```
   Main.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
   return weekDay;
          ^
   ```

This simply means it can't find the variable in the current scope. There's a lot to learn about this, but I'll just get to the point.

```
    // Return days
    public static String weekDay(int i, int[] array)
    {
        int[] displayWeekDay = searchTemp(array, i);
        String weekDay = "";
        for(i = 0; i < displayWeekDay.length; i++){

            //String weekDay = ""; Declare weekDay outside of the loop
            switch(i)
            {
                //Assign a value to weekDay, simply returning won't do it
                case 0: weekDay = "Sunday"; break;
                case 1: weekDay = "Monday"; break;
                case 2: weekDay = "Tuesday"; break;
                case 3: weekDay = "Wednesdays"; break;
                case 4: weekDay = "Thursday"; break;
                case 5: weekDay = "Friday"; break;
                case 6: weekDay = "Saturday"; break;
            }
        }
        return weekDay;
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: As per the discussion, this is what I would do in order to be able to print multiple days that had the highest temperature

```
//Call the function directly without putting a print statement around it
weekDay(maxTemp,tempList)); 
//...
// Return days
public static void weekDay(int i, int[] array) //Change the return type to void
{
    int[] displayWeekDay = searchTemp(array, i);
    for(i = 0; i < displayWeekDay.length; i++){
        switch(displayWeekDay[i])
        {
            //Print each one
            case 0: System.out.println("Sunday"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("Monday"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Tuesday"); break;
            case 3: System.out.println("Wednesday"); break;
            case 4: System.out.println("Thursday"); break;
            case 5: System.out.println("Friday"); break;
            case 6: System.out.println("Saturday"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird logic error, when it displays the day of the week that's the hottest, it keeps showing saturday, and only saturday. http://ideone.com/MYlbyS Here is my updated code

Comment: @Flinze I forgot to add the break statement after each case. Please see my edit.

Comment: After running my program again, it looks like there is a problem with my "weekday" method as everytime I run it, it only displays "Saturday" no matter what. What I'm trying to do with that method is to display the days of the week that are the hottest. Say a user enters 10, 18, 15, 15, 17, 18, 12.
Since 18 is the highest, it should display "Monday" and "Friday" as the hottest day of the week.
I have updated my code, I'm still not sure what's wrong now.
http://ideone.com/MYlbyS

Comment: @Flinze Hmm in your first version of the weekday function, you had return [day] in each of the cases. Was that the intention or did you intend to assign it to the variable weekDay?

Comment: I intended to return each day that was suppose to be the "hottest" day. I think I just added in the "weekDay" variable to get rid of a compilation error early on which said I needed to return something at the end of my method, even though I was already returning the days, so I just made up a variable "weekDay" so the error stopped.

Comment: @Flinze in that case, you could simply say return ""; or return null; The function expects you to return a string at each relevant case.

Comment: I'm still getting weird errors. Here is the input and output: Enter the hightest temperature of each day for a week (starting on Sunday): 
15
5
1
18
19
21
1
The average temperature of the week is: 11.43 degree 
The highest temperature of the week is: 21 degree
The coldest temperature of the week is: 1 degree
The hottest days of the week are: Sunday

Comment: @Flinze That looks like an error in your other function most likely. Check the line that says "int[] displayWeekDay = searchTemp(array, i);" in the function, and check the searchTemp function as well.

Comment: The other functions work fine as intended, my searchTemp method, in this case finds the "hottest" days and then display the index number. I just need to somehow translate that into String format corresponding correctly with each day of the week.

Comment: I think I kind of fixed it now, however it does not display multiple days of the week that have the same highest temperatures. E.g. when user inputs: 10,12,5,11,2,12,5. It displays only Monday, instead of both Monday and Friday. I have once again updated my code: http://ideone.com/CQfizn

Comment: @Flinze I'm seeing the issue now. I'm going to edit the code you sent and post the link to the edited version.

Comment: @Flinze the issue was that you were only returning one string in the weekDay function. Even if you put a loop, any time you call return it will exit that function and it won't continue that loop. So basically you have two options: Print the Day in the weekDay function, or store the relevant days in a String array or String vector and then return that and print from it.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing each issue on it's own:

1. "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int" issue

This is being caused by the line `System.out.print(weekDay(tempList,maxTemp));`. The method signature for the weekDay method is `public static String weekDay(int i, int[] array)` however the method is being called with arguments in the wrong order - `tempList` is of type `int[]` and `maxTemp` is of type `int`. Reversing the arguments in either the method call or the method signature will resolve the error.

2. "error: cannot find symbol"

This is an issue related to variable scope. When a variable is declared (e.g. `int i;` or `String name = "John";`), that variable can only be used within the scope that it is declared in. In the `weekDay` method the `weekDay` variable is declared inside the `for` loop (i.e. inside of the braces associated with the `for` loop). As such the `weekDay` variable only has the scope of the `for` loop, and cannot be referenced outside of that scope. Moving the declaration of `weekDay` outside of the `for` loop will fix the issue. See [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) for more information on variable scope rules.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, think about the API first, input later.  This implementation assumes JDK 8 and lambdas:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 3/19/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107614/java-displaying-the-temperature-statistics-of-the-week-using-arrays
 */
public class TemperatureHistory {

    private Map<Date, Double> temperatureHistory = new TreeMap<>();

    public void addDataPoint(Date date, Double temperature) {
        if (date != null && temperature != null) {
            this.temperatureHistory.put(date, temperature);
        }
    }

    public Double getAverageTemperature() {
        double averageTemperature = 0.0;
        if (this.temperatureHistory.size() > 0) {
            averageTemperature = this.temperatureHistory.values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(value -> value));
        }
        return averageTemperature;
    }

    public Double getMaxTemperature() {
        return this.temperatureHistory.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .max((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue()))
                .get()
                .getValue();
    }

    public Double getMinTemperature() {
        return this.temperatureHistory.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .min((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue()))
                .get()
                .getValue();
    }

    public Date getFirstDateForTemperature(Double temperature) {
        return this.temperatureHistory.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(temperature))
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public Date getDateMinTemperature() {
        return this.getFirstDateForTemperature(this.getMinTemperature());
    }

    public Date getDateMaxTemperature() {
        return this.getFirstDateForTemperature(this.getMaxTemperature());
    }
}
```

Comment: Lambdas are a bit too much for a beginner to digest. But may be useful to other readers.

Comment: Agreed.  I did it to practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String weekDay(int i, int[] array)
```

In this method, you're suppose to return a String type value

edit: change the string variable to other name. you can't have it the same as the method's name

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement of you main method you do `System.out.print(weekDay(tempList,maxTemp));`
weekDay takes an `int` as the first argument, but tempList is of type `int[]`. You should swap the order of tempList and maxTemp either in your method call or definition.